# Solr Map reduce indexer tool not able to fetch aliases through zk

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

Hi While working with MapReduceIndexerTool with solr 4.10 cloud, the code is successfully able to connect to Zookeeper, but while fetching the aliases.json, it fails to fetch the data. Below is the command and stack trace:

**command:**

```
hadoop   --config /etc/hadoop/conf   jar target/search-mr-*-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool   -D 'mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx500m'   --log4j src/test/resources/log4j.properties   --morphline-file /home/impadmin/app_quotes_morphline.conf   --output-dir hdfs://impetus-i0056.impetus.co.in:8020/user/impadmin/MapReduceIndexerTool/output2   --zk-host 172.26.45.69:9983/solr   --collection app.quotes   hdfs://impetus-i0056.impetus.co.in:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/kst
```

**stack trace:**

WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
1    [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient  - Using default ZkCredentialsProvider
87   [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager  - Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
114  [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager  - Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@1568159 name:ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:172.26.45.69:9983/solr got event WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null path:null type:None
115  [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager  - Client is connected to ZooKeeper
115  [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient  - Using default ZkACLProvider
Exception in thread "main" net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.ArgumentParserException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find expected information for SolrCloud in ZooKeeper: 172.26.45.69:9983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.verifyZKStructure(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:1418)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.run(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:716)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.run(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.main(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find expected information for SolrCloud in ZooKeeper: 172.26.45.69:9983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.ZooKeeperInspector.extractDocCollection(ZooKeeperInspector.java:88)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.ZooKeeperInspector.extractShardUrls(ZooKeeperInspector.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.verifyZKStructure(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:1415)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /aliases.json
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$7.execute(SolrZkClient.java:351)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$7.execute(SolrZkClient.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.getData(SolrZkClient.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.ZooKeeperInspector.checkForAlias(ZooKeeperInspector.java:164)
    at org.apache.solr.hadoop.ZooKeeperInspector.extractDocCollection(ZooKeeperInspector.java:85)
    ... 12 more

Please help me to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the URL that was being hit to access zk solr configs. thus correcting the URL solved the issue. In case of embedded solr instance the URL does not have application solr available, but rather puts it directly under zk root.